# Natural Language Proccessing detect similarity between phrases

Tags: python, nlp

I have been working on a natural language proccessing algorithm for an app of mine. Currently, all is well. However I am struggling to compare like phrases. For example, how can I detect that the phrases "right now" and "current" are relevant to each other? My algorithm is being written in python and am working a lot with the popular NLTK library. Is there any good way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate [NLP: any easy and good methods to find semantic similarity between words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441361/nlp-any-easy-and-good-methods-to-find-semantic-similarity-between-words)

Comment: Awesome, @NateJ nice find.