# associated words

Tags: nlp

I am developing a program but stuck on a particular hurdle. I need to find words associated with other words. EG "green" might be associated with "environment", "leaf", "earth", "wind", "electric", "hybrid", etc. All I can find is Google Sets. Is there any other resource that is better?

Comment: What kind of association?  Synonyms?  Words that generally appear near each other in sentences?

Comment: not synonyms, but words that would spring to mind when someone is given that word. Now how one would figure this out in an automated fashion, that is part of the challenge I guess.

Comment: somewhat like the bogus psychological test of word association.

Comment: Similar but perhaps not quite the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610399/finding-related-words-specifically-physical-objects-to-a-specific-word/611248#611248

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a large text collection (say Wikipedia, Project Gutenberg) you can use co-occurrence scores extract this kind of data. See e.g. [Padó and Lapata](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.128.3332) and the references therein.

I recently built a [tool](http://github.com/larsmans/wikiassoc) that mines this kind of associations from Wikipedia database dumps by another method. It requires a lot of memory though; other folks have tried to do the same using randomized methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a resource of semantically related words, I've just recently developed an API that takes a query and returns semantically related words. It offers parts of speech, relationships to the query word, and a word similarity measurement.

https://kiingo.co/rapid-associations-api

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of this API.