# what are the different techniques for comparing 2 words semantically? Which one is the best among them?

Tags: cpu-word, semantics, wordnet, semantic-analysis

Right now, I am at the starting point of a project in  which I am supposed to compare two words semantically.

I came to know about WordNet wherein we find distance between words to find how similar they are in terms of their meaning.

It would be really helpful if you can suggest some more techniques and which method would be the best one.

Comment: you can look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610399/finding-related-words-specifically-physical-objects-to-a-specific-word?rq=1

Comment: This is a whole research field: we can't answer in one StackOverflow answer. I'd suggest you to start with [those slides about word similarity](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs124/lec/sem#page=29) (it starts at page 29).